# Quarternion group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having issues showing each element has an inverse. I could do it the arduous and check for all 8 elements way but I'd rather understand the solution in 3). I understand that the inverse is B^-s.A^-r.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible? And therefore that $B^{-s}A^{-r}$ makes sense for all $r,s \in \mathbb Z$? Once you've done that it's just iteratively using the relation $BA=A^3B$ to write $B^{-s}A^{-r} = A^mB^n$ for some integers $m,n$ and hence conclude $B^{-s}A^{-r}$ is in the set you defined as $Q_8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we start with $B^{-s}A^{-r}$. Pre-multiplying by some power of $B^4=1$ and post-multiplying by some multiple of $A^4=1$ we can reduce this to $B^kA^l$ where $0\le k,l\le 3$.

Then the argument you used with part 2 applies - use $B^kA^l=(A^0B^k)(A^lB^0)$